# weird 'piratebay.org' hostname on my computer?

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, home-networking, hostname

It appeared many days ago. I was writing down `thepiratebay.org` on the URL search bar on my browser. But I unintentionally hit enter on `piratebay.org` and then firefox loads this:

[My apache 'index of' home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSlK1.png)

Have you ever seen this before?

Some more info about:

[terminal1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhxXU.png)

Terminal 2:

```
iqbal@iqbal:~$ nslookup piratebay.org
;; Got SERVFAIL reply from 127.0.0.1, trying next server
Server:     209.222.18.222
Address:    209.222.18.222#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   piratebay.org
Address: 127.0.0.1

iqbal@iqbal:~$ host piratebay.org
piratebay.org has address 127.0.0.1
Host piratebay.org not found: 4(NOTIMP)
iqbal@iqbal:~$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   iqbal
#127.0.1.1  www.facebook.com
192.168.1.34    iqbal   omen.iqbal
192.168.1.33    iqbal   omen.iqbal

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Terminal 3:

```
iqbal@iqbal:~$ hostnamectl status
   Static hostname: iqbal
         Icon name: computer-laptop
           Chassis: laptop
        Machine ID: bb5927fcc4fa49d6842b425a4bd2108f
           Boot ID: 6bc61f826871450e88f9523bca4881cf
  Operating System: Ubuntu 16.10
            Kernel: Linux 4.8.0-34-generic
      Architecture: x86-64
iqbal@iqbal:~$ ps aux|grep piratebay
iqbal     6524  0.0  0.0  14232   980 pts/4    S+   20:50   0:00 grep --color=auto piratebay
iqbal@iqbal:~$ lsof|grep piratebay //->nothing here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone set DNS A record of piratebay.org to 127.0.0.1, so that's loopbacking to server which is on your computer.

See: [dig](https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=piratebay.org&type=A&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=)

```
piratebay.org.      3599    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

Comment: can you explain how to delete a DNS record?

Comment: @iqbal_cs Only the owner of this domain can. You can block it locally in /etc/hosts, for example adding "0.0.0.0 piratebay.org" to it, or - if you don't want to see your files, by just disabling directory listing of Apache, or disabling/removing Apache entirely. BTW, these files can only see anyone on that PC, not everyone in the world - for me 127.0.0.1 (and piratebay.org) displays my own local server's webpage.

Comment: oh really? I thought It was something very strange. Even though, do you know how specifically this happened?

Comment: 1) You somehow installed Apache server on your computer with probably directory indexing enabled 2) Owner of piratebay.org changed it's DNS settings to localhost (127.0.0.1). It's same for everyone in the world, not just you, who have this configuration (server on port 80 on their's computer).

Comment: My apache is the one which comes pre-installed with ubuntu. What would be the point of having `piratebay.org` as an alias? Also I noticed that the access to that "hostname" loads slower than `localhost`

Comment: @iqbal_cs It loads slower because it needs to resolve this hostname in DNS system, not just open local port 80. There is no point of it, PirateBay.org owners did it probably for fun. This is not dependent on your system, or on any system - piratebay.org right now will resolve to 127.0.0.1 on every single computer in the world (no matter if it's Windows, Linux, Mac or any other OS - unless obviously owner's of that system didn't configured it otherwise). There is not piratebay.org alias on your Apache, but it's just defaults to localhost by default for unknown  hostnames.

Comment: @Ramhound - we're talking about piratebay.org and not thepiratebay.org or similar.

Comment: @Ramhound does `piratebay.org` work for you too?

Comment: Why would I intestinally go to the wrong website?

Comment: @Ramhound I don't know, but you can easily check by multiple online DNS tools that it's A record is set to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Ramhound Hex said `piratebay.org` could be resolved by any computer. Just curiosity.

Comment: The dns records for that site was last changed 5 years ago.....

Comment: @Ramhound And your point being...?

Comment: @Ramhound your comment contradicts Hex's answer. Post another answer showing your approach please

Comment: How do you figure I contradicted Hex?  The domains dns was last changed 5 years ago.  That's my only point